# EditText Accept Numbers between two numbers

Tags: java, android

I have edit text view in my layout like below. I am able to set digits to accept but I want set limit to accept between two numbers like 1 to 100 from java. I am not able to get idea how I can achieve this. My edittext is like below

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userInputDialog"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dialogueError"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="120"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:digits="0123456789"
        android:textColorHint="@color/toolbar_text"
        android:textColor="@color/toolbar_text"
        android:inputType="number" />
```

Let me know if anyone can help me here for same. Thanks!

Comment: https://acomputerengineer.com/2015/12/16/limit-number-range-in-edittext-in-android-using-inputfilter/

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
    android:maxLength="2"
```

To set it to only 2 chars length.
You can also use

```
android:inputType="number"
```

For numbers only